# Cannot give more than 32GB of RAM to a Debian squeeze under Xen 6.1

Tags: debian, virtual-machines, xen, debian-squeeze

Under XEN 6.1, I tried to give a debian squeeze VM more than 32GB of RAM. But the Xen Center gave me this: "The amount of physical memory allocated to this VM is greater than the total memory of its home server".

The host server has much more RAM than this (128GB). Is it a Xen limit? If so, is there a workaround?

@David Schwartz

```
# xl info
host                   : xxx
release                : 2.6.32.43-0.4.1.xs1.6.10.734.170748xen
version                : #1 SMP Mon Sep 10 13:28:39 EDT 2012
machine                : i686
nr_cpus                : 16
max_cpu_id             : 15
nr_nodes               : 2
cores_per_socket       : 4
threads_per_core       : 2
cpu_mhz                : 3292
hw_caps                : xxx
virt_caps              : hvm hvm_directio
total_memory           : 131030
free_memory            : 77973
free_cpus              : 0
xen_major              : 4
xen_minor              : 1
xen_extra              : .3
xen_caps               : xen-3.0-x86_64 xen-3.0-x86_32p hvm-3.0-x86_32 hvm-3.0-x86_32p <BR>hvm-3.0-x86_64
xen_scheduler          : credit
xen_pagesize           : 4096
platform_params        : virt_start=0xf7c00000
changeset          : trunk.xxx (xxx)
commandline        : mem=1024G dom0_mem=752M,max:752M watchdog_timeout=300 cpuid_mask_xsave_eax=0 lowmem_emergency_pool=1M crashkernel=64M@32M console=vga dom0_max_vcpus=1-4
cc_compiler            : gcc version xxx (Red Hat xxx)
<BR>cc_compile_by          : root
cc_compile_domain      : xxx
cc_compile_date        : Fri Nov 23 08:27:12 EST 2012
xend_config_format     : 4

xl list
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0   738     4     r-----  166282.8
vm1                                         183  2048     1     -b----     703.1
vm2                                   184 32768     2     -b----    3723.0
vm3                              185  4096     2     ------    3923.9
vm4                                   186  2048     1     -b----    2238.3
vm5                                    189  4095     1     -b----    3724.8
vm6                                       190  4096     1     -b----     601.2
vm7                                       191  1024     1     -b----    1824.0
```

Comment: How much memory did you [give dom0](http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/XenBestPractices)? What is the output of `xl info` and `xl list`?

Comment: @David Schwartz : I added xl info and list infos above. The memory allocated to Dom0 is 752M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XenServer 6.1 doesn't support assigning more than 32 GB RAM for Linux Debian Squeeze VMs. But you can use the CLI for that (unsupported). Your VM should be shutdown for this configuration.

Example: 
`xe vm-param-set uuid=<VM UUID> memory-static-max=64GiB memory-dynamic-max=64GiB memory-dynamic-min=64GiB`